# Convert angle to clock time

Tags: code-golf, math, clock

Your task is to make a program or function that takes a nonnegative integer (or a different convenient format to represent it) that represents an angle measure in degrees from 0 to 180 (inclusive) as input and outputs every possible time (in hours and minutes; no seconds) on an analog clock where the measure of the smaller angle between the hour hand and minute hand is equal to the inputted angle measure.

## Rules

- Output can be a list of times, a string of the times with separators, or multiple outputs of times.
- The times can be formatted in any way that can be identifiable as
  clock times by humans, such as `hh:mm` or a list of the hours and
  minutes.
- The times should be from 12:00 to 11:59 (e.g. `0:00` and `22:00` are invalid outputs).
- Standard loopholes apply.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes in each language wins.

## Test cases

```
Input    | Output
---------|------------
0        | 12:00
90       | 3:00, 9:00
180      | 6:00
45       | 4:30, 7:30
30       | 1:00, 11:00
60       | 2:00, 10:00
120      | 4:00, 8:00
15       | 5:30, 6:30
135      | 1:30, 10:30
1        | 4:22, 7:38
42       | 3:24, 8:36
79       | 3:02, 8:58
168      | 1:36, 10:24
179      | 1:38, 10:22
115      | 1:50, 10:10
```

Interestingly, there are only two possible times in hours and minutes (except for 0 and 180 degrees) for every integer (or number with a fractional part of 0.5) degree input and on an analog clock the times represent horizontally flipped images of each other.

Comment: Suggest the watch photographers preferred times of `10:10`/`10:09` as testcases! :D

Comment: Just to clarify: there are 11 or 22 possible times for each angle, but only 1 or 2 of those have a whole number of minutes.

Comment: @Nitrodon Yes. Seconds are not dealt with for this challenge.

Comment: When there are two times, does the order matter? I guess not?

Comment: @Steffan It does not matter.

Comment: Is it acceptable to output the same value twice for 0/180?

Comment: @MatthewJensen No, it should only be outputted once.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
60Ḷ12p×“<¿‘Hạ/eʋƇØ°_,Ɗ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a non-negative integer in \$[0,180]\$ and yields a list of pairs of `[hour, minute]` of a twelve-hour analogue clock.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9qZWxsef//NjDhuLYxMnDDl@KAnDzCv@KAmEjhuqEvZcqLxofDmMKwXyzGiv/Dh8WS4bmY//80NA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/M4OGObYZGBYenP2qYY3No/6OGGR4Pdy3UTz3Vfaz98IxDG@J1jnX9P9x@dNLDnTN0HLKAqhR07RQeNczVjPz/P9pAx9JAx9DCQMfEVMfYQMcMyDECYlMdQ2Mg1jEx0jG31DE0s9AxBNGGprEA).

#### How?

If we label straight up (12:00) as \$0\$ degrees, then at a given exact minute of \$h\$ hours and \$m\$ minutes, the minute hand is at \$\frac{360 m}{60}\$, while the hour hand is at \$\frac{360 h}{12}+\frac{360m}{60 \times 12}\$ degrees. A clockwise angle between the hour hand and minute hand is, therefore:

$$A=\frac{360 h}{12}+\frac{360m}{60 \times 12}-\frac{360 m}{60}$$
$$A=30h+\frac{m}{2}-6m$$
$$A=30h-\frac{11m}{2}$$

The code makes all of the times as `[h, m]` pairs and filters them for when the absolute value of the above angle \$A\$ is either equal to the input or \$360\$ minus the input.

```
60Ḷ12p×“<¿‘Hạ/eʋƇØ°_,Ɗ - Link: integer, A in [0,180]
60                     - sixty
  Ḷ                    - lowered range -> [0..59]
   12                  - twelve
     p                 - Cartesian product -> Times = [[1,0],...,[1,59],...,[12,59]]
                     Ɗ - last three links as a monad - f(A):
                 Ø°    -   360
                   _   -   minus A
                    ,  -   paired with A -> Angles=[360-A,A]
                Ƈ      - filter keep those Times for which:
               ʋ       -   last four links as a dyad - f(Time,Angles):
       “<¿‘            -     code-page indices      = [60,11]
      ×                -     Time times [60,11]    -> [60h,11m]
          H            -     halve                 -> [30h,11m/2]
             /         -     reduce by:
            ạ          -       absolute difference -> abs(30h-11m/2)
              e        -     exists in Angles?
```

Comment: As stated in the rules, the times should be from 12:00 to 11:59, so the hour number can not be 0. This also only outputs one possible time for inputs 90, 30, 60, etc.

Comment: @Yousername I realised about the bug while writing up a test suite for my previous answer, that's fixed and so is the \$12\$ vs \$0\$ hour output formatting issue.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 44 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [@Steffan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/92689/steffan).

```
{}⋃Mod[458{#,-#},720,60]~IntegerDigits~60&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@7@69lF3s29@SrSJqUW1so6ucq2OuZGBjplBbJ1nXklqemqRS2Z6ZklxnZmB2v@Aosy8kmhlBV07hbRo5dhYBTUFfQeFagMdBUsgNrQAEiamOgrGQNoMJGAEIoAChsYgAihppKNgbglkmlkACXPL2v8A)

Comment: [-1 byte with the union operator](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@7@69lF3s2deSWp6apFLZnpmSXG0b35KtImpRbWyjq5yrY65kYGOmUEsCKv9DyjKzCuJVlbQtVNIi1aOjVVQU9B3UKg20FGwBGJDCyBhYqqjYAykzUACRiACKGBoDCKAkkY6CuaWQKaZBZAwt6z9DwA "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") (literally using a tip you posted, lol)

Answer (score 4):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 44 bytes

```
a->Set([[(b\60-1)%12+1,b%60]|b<-458*[a,-a]])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN3USde2CU0s0oqM1kmLMDHQNNVUNjbQNdZJUzQxia5JsdE1MLbSiE3V0E2NjNaF6YhMLCnIqNRIVdO0UCooy80qATCUQR0khTSNRU1NHIdpAR8ESiA0tgISJqY6CMZA2AwkYgQiggKExiABKGukomFsCmWYWQMLcEmbJggUQGgA)

The `%12` trick is stolen from [G B's Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246335/9288).

Comment: Any reason why you chose `458` and not `262`?

Comment: @Neil No reason.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>82 79 55</s> 47 bytes

```ruby
->d{[k=262*d,-k].map{|c|[c/60%-12+12,c%60]}|[]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6lOjrb1sjMSCtFRzc7Vi83saC6JrkmOlnfzEBV19BI29BIJ1nVzCC2tiY6tvZ/gUJatGEsF4gygFDGQFrDQE/P0MJAE6I7pQYkngJUDQA)

Stolen from various other answers: the angle between the two hands is increased by 1 degree after 4h22m.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 55 bytes

```
\(a,b=458*c(a,-a))unique(cbind((b%/%60-1)%%12+1,b%%60))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZFLbgIxDIbFtqeIVEVK6IywncdkkLgJGwYYiQ1SK2bHgnt0M63UQ8FpmsRIJFnk4c_2_yf5_vmaf8fN33QZ23DvtmrXDBvrwnIfd-1O6-l8-pyOaj-czgelBrmSHlrUUiJ9YDPIeNSayx-L26hACP0u8rgKpDXA26h6KIImxhrRM8EAL-I5Zl2RbdcmZndxjsSUfTD3QeQiXyJiBE8NgrJfQuFJSiWXlTwroXGlkuF2jERljyjbC8k4Vdckm4SMj6Tr6wegRFyqQR8qIZ-FyCbU9RUKjCghrOw5tofAHzHPvP4D)

Port of [@alephalpha's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246339/55372).

Outputs as a matrix with hours in the first column and minutes in the second.

---

#### [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>84</s> 72 bytes

*Edit: -9 bytes thanks to [@Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l).*

```
\(a)t(which(outer(1:12,0:59,\(x,y)abs(30*x-5.5*y)%in%c(a,360-a)),T))-0:1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZHBSgMxEIbx6lMESiEpWZmZbLJJwLsP4LGXtbi0lwp1S1vw4Ht4WQUfSp_GZKdgkkMC8838_5_k4_MwfQ3338dxaPzPw1r2apSn7W6zlS_H8fkgMSJpiDbotTzri-qfXqWB1bmxd3Z1UcvdfrmRvTYOml4p_ahUAxFZ7_fmfZAghFqIeb0JpAhwO8gARdGkmhaBCXr4J45rrS2622hSd5f2REypg7MOIg-5EhEjuHoQlHoZ-Sspnezs5NgJjS2dDMsxElU8ojmez8Gpuia12ci4RLpQPwBlYvMMOl8ZudmI2oy6UCHPiDLCKp7leAj8EdPE5x8)

Outputs as a matrix with hours in the first row and minutes in the second.

The formula looks exactly like in [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246338/55372).

Comment: I think you can replace your `abs` argument with `x%*%c(30,-5.5)` to save a few.

Comment: Or rather use `outer` for [75 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZHBSgMxEIbx6lMESiEpWZmZbLJJwCfw6rGXtbi0lwp1S1vw4Ht4WQUfSp_GZKdgkkMC8838_5_k4_MwfQ3338dxaPzPw1r2apSjPG13m618OY7PB4kRSUO0Qa_lWV9U__QqDazOjb2zq4ta7vbLjey1cdD0SulHpRqIqFjy9-Z9kCCEWoh5vQmkCHA7yABF0aSaFoEJevgnjmutLbrbaFJ3l_ZETKmDsw4iD7kSESO4ehCUehn5Kymd7Ozk2AmNLZ0MyzESVTyiOZ7Pwam6JrXZyLhEulA_AGVi8ww6Xxm52YjajLpQIc-IMsIqnuV4CPwR08TnHw)

Comment: @KirillL. that's a nice idea - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 45 bytes

```
ＮθＥΦ³⁶⁰№﹪×¹¹⟦±ιι⟧³⁶⁰θ⪫Ｅ⟦∨÷ι³⁰¦¹²⊗﹪ι³⁰⟧﹪%02dλ:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYy9CsIwGEV3nyIEhAQitPVnsKNFqGB1cCsdahP0gzRpY9LXj1/9Wc5w7uF2z9Z1ttUxlmYIvgr9XTk28nxxdWA8O7cDO4L2KNe7RJCDDbO1MmjLbtCrF0tTQepKPVqvGHBBoEFgjBw54mTBfH7qi2Ol8QVMIDHFaG7SDFHYcNdK/o@/G28E@Qm6TDJJBdHzId1Tznke42YbV5N@Aw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The angle between the hands increases by 11° every two minutes.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the angle.

```
ＥΦ³⁶⁰
```

Loop over all times from `12:00` to `11:58` in multiples of 2 minutes.

```
№﹪×¹¹⟦±ιι⟧³⁶⁰θ
```

Keep only those times where the angle between the hands or its negation equals the input.

```
⪫Ｅ⟦∨÷ι³⁰¦¹²⊗﹪ι³⁰⟧﹪%02dλ:
```

Format the doubled number of minutes as a time.

If outputting `12:00` or `06:00` twice for inputs of `0` and `180` respectively had been legal, then for <s>41</s> 39 bytes:

```
ＮθＥ×⟦²⁶²¦⁴⁵⁸⟧θ⪫Ｅ⟦⊕﹪⊖÷ι⁶⁰¦¹²﹪ι⁶⁰⟧﹪%02dλ:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYuxCsIwFEV3vyIEhBeIUENbxK5dKlQc3EqH2DwwkCZtTPr70arocuGee@5wl35w0qTU2CmGcxxv6GFm1ebitQ3QygmuesQHdKIUnOTFoedkZpycnLbvuWvs4HFEG1BB61Q0Dmr8o8aGWi9aIWhOyoy9vnux5tf90P7X6TYTinJiVoceKWOsSikv0m4xTw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: The number of minutes is given by the angle multiplied by `262` or `458` (effectively modulo `720`, but this is calculated by taking the hour modulo `12`, with a zero result becoming `12`).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>79</s> 78 bytes

Only works in locales with UTC that use the 12 hour clock.

```js
f=
n=>(n%180?[262,458]:[262]).map(m=>new Date(m*n*6e4).toTimeString().slice(0,5))
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=180 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value|0)><pre id=o>
```

Longer version that works everywhere, except on days with DST transitions:

```js
f=
n=>(n%180?[262,458]:[262]).map(m=>new Date(0,0,0,0,m*n).toLocaleString('en-US',{timeStyle:'short'}).slice(0,5))
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=180 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value|0)><pre id=o>
```

Longest version that always works everywhere:

```js
f=
n=>(n%180?[262,458]:[262]).map(m=>new Date(m*n*6e4).toLocaleString('en-US',{timeStyle:'short',timeZone:'utc'}).slice(0,5))
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=180 oninput=o.textContent=f(this.value|0)><pre id=o>
```

Explanation: The angle between the hands is `1°` at `04:22` and its reflection, which correspond to `262` and `458` minutes past midnight. Any larger angle can be obtained by simply multiplying the desired angle by those two numbers of minutes.

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @MatthewJensen.

Comment: It doesn't work for `0` as input, though I personally think that banning `00:00` is totally arbitrary. Anyway I would love an explanation of the algorithm. What's going on with those dates?

Comment: @anotherOne Whoops, I forgot that function was 24-hour. I've changed it to use a different function now.

Comment: `(n%180?[262,458]:[262])` is shorter than using `slice()`

Comment: You could also use `[262,458].slice(~n%180)`

Comment: I would have never thought about just multiplying the minutes of `1°`. Nice one.

Comment: Noticed an interesting formatting difference between the three versions: when outputting two times, versions 2 and 3 place a space *before* the comma, while version one does not put a space on either side of the comma

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>65</s> 64 bytes

```hs
f a=[[h,m]|h<-[1..12],m<-[0..59],elem(abs(h*30-5.5*m))[a,360-a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYnNDoIwEIRfZY@FLE1/LEIib6Anj00PawKpsUUiGC@@e108zDdfZiKtjzGlUiagwfuIOXzjqfFaSm0CZlYlpesDjmnMgm6riLVVjZOuzlXlCW2rGgqhZLrPMECm5QJieW/X7XWeQcIanx@uqQKvEHqO7hgHh2C5230wO3jQdgefBuHYs7Yd42/ahfID)

Ironically, I wrote this to try some taste of Curry, but it failed with some errors I struggle to understand. Worked in Haskell though...

Thanks to pajonk for -1.

Comment: tio link is broke

Comment: Sorry, fixed now

Comment: `Float` is not an instance of `Enum` in Curry.

Comment: Shouldn't `11/2` -> `5.5` work for -1 byte? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYnNDoIwEIRfZY@FLE1/LEIib6Anj00PawKpsUUiGC@@e108zDdfZiKtjzGlUiagwfuIOXzjqfFaSm0CZlYlpesDjmnMgm6riLVVjZOuzlXlCW2rGgqhZLrPMECm5QJieW/X7XWeQcIanx@uqQKvEHqO7hgHh2C5230wO3jQdgefBuHYs7Yd42/ahfID "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: @pajonk, Hehe, apparently I managed to notice the same when playing with your R answer, but not in my own :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `M`, 22 bytes

```
6d59Ẋ'30₀›½"*÷εkR⁰-⁰"c
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJNIiwiIiwiNmQ1OeG6iiczMOKCgOKAusK9XCIqw7fOtWtS4oGwLeKBsFwiYyIsIiIsIjE3OSJd)

You can also [run all the test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m720rLIiMWfBcoc0K8OaQ4uXlpak6VrcVDRLMbV8uKtL3djgUVPDo4Zdh_YqaR3efm5rdtChpbqHliolLylOSi5eY23NdWy2Q5q19aPGbojWpdFKvkqxNx2iDXQULIHY0AJImJjqKBgDaTOQgBGIAAoYGoMIoKSRjoK5JZBpZgEkwCxD01iIaQA) but be prepared to wait at least a minute.

### How?

```
6d59Ẋ'30₀›½"*÷εkR⁰-⁰"c
6d                     # Push 6 doubled, which is 12 (this is to avoid having to put a space after it)
  59                   # Push 59
    Ẋ                  # Cartesian product of these two numbers, which are implicitly cast to inclusive zero ranges
     '                 # Filter this list for:
      30               #  Push 30
        ₀›             #  Push 10 + 1, which is 11. This is to avoid having to put a space before it
          ½            #  Halve to make 5.5
           "           #  Pair these two values to [30, 5.5]
            *          #  Multiply both by the current item
             ÷         #  Push both values of the multiplied pair to the sstack
              ε        #  Absolute difference of the two
               kR⁰-    #  Push 360 minus the input
                   ⁰"  #  Pair with the input
                     c #  Does this list contain the absolute difference pushed earlier?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), <s>77</s> 72 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to Arnauld!

```javascript
a=>new Set([a*262,a*458].map(m=>(m/60%12|0||12)+(m%60>9?':':':0')+m%60))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9db5swFIbv/SvOxVrshjq2@ShJBFUvNqnSLiblMo0aK3IaJr4ETqat6W/PsIEASBg/et/Hx7/lWTb7Oq304zm6HuKrjJNC/YG10ngjH0QoXPngB9GW5rLCeZzgfB6yOy4u7HLhgsxwfheyZPHsLM3LHDIzgJDrCu0Qg/65ABdLxtCC3YDX7l1YGMojNtDQ7P3glvKXXpt6ar/IG7vcdrlZUDhi0WFmnYKNDoMjS0dzYM2hMXMvGM1epzAYJmMIYceIkC8mVxC@EXshelpMLyYMDSLEw2giDq1Y@IgPaYujDgvE@WSMoBuDM7Sjuk5zTGhTZanGzlvhEHoo6@9yf8RZWiiIE/hEAPuyaDRs0qI6aRfeXShPuv2FGN6HrgsO2bbA1Ho2h9nbBeZkdTPUqjllpnbAlawb9VpobKVkEqpk07SR7giaqeJDHyGO475Nm/Sfgvv7IaDOqv6LdZrbafvMUTYWjd4yUzQrP7C1P4Pz62W9dmAJzo@X15/t9P3dnMek3WwopZ1p68LQMOkd/vbZnftFdq37i6yu/wE)

Comment: [72 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/NauMwFEb3eoq7aLHUuIok26qTYJcuplDoYiDLNBARnKkH/2ErGYa6z55KchLbAot7@O7h0191Ut2@zRv9eIrPh@SskrTK/sE603ijHoQUvnoIo3hLS9XgMklxOZfsnoue9T0XZIbLe8nSxbO3tId5ZGYBIecV2iEGl68HLpaMoQW7gcDMPiws5TG7UmnnMLqlwmVgUk/mj4Jxl7tdbi8kRywGzJxTsNFhcezoaI6cWVozD6LRHAwKi2FSQwhXI0ahmDxBhFYcSPS0mD5MWBrFiMt4IpZOLELEr2mH4wELxPmkRjTU4AztqG7zEhPaNUWusfdReYQe6vaX2n/iIq8ySFL4QgD7uuo0bPKqOWof6qM29xYSsJnL8hxmHz3MyeoWb7PuWGiTOuBGtV32VmnsDGQSalTXmcigvPbwwfTITln7H@u8dC0GGf1UnUOjoi4yWtR/sBM9g/f7Zb32YAne68vbuzFdOnuPqRk2lNLBtPXhumHTO3z3NXT4Jjvj/iar8w8) if you return a Set.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 81 bytes

```
>{-,}{$[x=$1*2],$[720-x]}
eval h={1..12}\;m={0..59}';<$[h%12*60-m*11]&&<<<$h:$m;'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYw7DoJAGAZ7TvEVKwhhyf6Ly0Meta01Uhgj2UJCgo8QCSexITEWHonbiNFiMplmHs_7WY_TpmpaEJYCsQBFAisFXyCYQ84okD-DlUQYg4II9DUpG0vjeNANGMHiPLde10vFo2mb99wdelZ0GSNHli4rQil4Vw7G8bY_QWc9eR7JYZfUWS88T8WDlaSs0AuSTiB47RCVppmmKdNrVif_8butwTkcw_71OP78AQ)

Damn floating point errors!

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 89 bytes

```
.+
$*_¶$&$*_
\G_
262$*
_
458$*
1{720}

D`
G`.
%`^(.{60})*(.*)
$#1:0$.2
%`^0
12
:0(..)
:$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYwxDoMwEAT7fUWkHBF2otOdwcZQR@ITUXCKFDQponSIb/EAPuaYYjTFrPb7/s2fV858Bdlp3@hShMc4wQVHFhNaH4t16ZyswD1hTIwqPWtegqzG1mwN6KyDELsjCNRhkJrZYCDNlUn7htspC/rSopRLNIJwDAse2hTQOnQ9NEToYfV/) Outputs times on separate lines but link is to test suite that joins with comma for convenience. Explanation:

```
.+
$*_¶$&$*_
```

Convert to unary twice.

```
\G_
262$*
_
458$*
```

Multiply the first copy by `262` and the second by `458`.

```
1{720}

D`
G`.
```

Reduce modulo `720` and deduplicate.

```
%`^(.{60})*(.*)
$#1:0$.2
%`^0
12
:0(..)
:$1
```

Format as a time.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
lambda n:{(n*i//60%-12+12,n*i%60)for i in(262,458)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYlBCsIwEEX3nmI2hUSnNJk0MS14EzcVCQZ0Wko3RXr2OHEx7///Ztm318yupNu9vKfP4zkBj1/F59x1wTStpYsllNkEo9O8QobMigJh76M@SlUsCgzCIGejoPcITjJUQRUirKuQJyFcB6khCv7N@vEEsKyZN5UUa11@)

Ported from various other answers.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 25 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
12L59Ýâʒ30T>;‚*ÆÄU360α‚Xå
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/246338/52210), and the output-format is also the same: a (1 or 2-sized) list of pair(s) of \$[h,m]\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f0MjH1PLw3MOLTk0yNgixs37UMEvrcNvhllBjM4NzG4G8iMNLgaoA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf8NjXxMLQ/PPbzo1CRjgxA760cNs7QOtx1uCT20zsXYzODcRqBAxOGl/2t1/kcb6Fga6BhaGOiYmOoYG@iYATlGQGyqY2gMxDomRjrmljqGZhY6hiDa0DQWAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
12L           # Push a list in the range [1,12]
59Ý           # Push a list in the range [0,59]
   â          # Cartesian product of both lists to create all possible pairs
    ʒ         # Filter these pairs by:
     30       #  Push 30
     T>;      #  Push 5.5 (10 +1 /2)
        ‚     #  Pair them together
         *    #  Multiply the values in the pairs [30h,5.5m]
          Æ   #  Reduce this pair by subtracting
           Ä  #  Convert it to its absolute value
            U #  Pop and store this value in variable `X`
     360α     #  Get the absolute difference of the (implicit) input and 360
         ‚    #  Pair the (implicit) input with this 360-input
          Xå  #  Check if value `X` is in this pair
              # (after which the filtered result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, 98 bytes

```
=LET(t,ROW(1:720)/1440,h,HOUR(t),m,MINUTE(t),a,ABS(30*h-11*m/2),FILTER(h&","&m,(a=A1)+(a=360-A1)))
```

Input is in the cell A1. Output is wherever the formula is and - usually - the cell below it.

[image: Screenshot]

The LET() function allows you to define variables for later reference. Here's each piece explained.

- `t,ROW(1:720)/1440` an array of time values from 0.0 to 0.5 (noon) broken into 1 minute long pieces.
- `h,HOUR(t)` an array the same length as `t` but just the hours.
- `m,MINUTE(t)` an array the same length as `t` but just the minutes.
- `a,ABS(30*h-11*m/2)` math based on other answers here.
- `h&","&m` combines the two arrays into the output format desired.
- `(a=A1)+(a=360-A1)` checks if the math matches the input angle.
- `FILTER(~,~)` returns just the outputs where the match matched the angle.

---

I also found this solution that clocks in at 103 bytes and outputs the results into a single cell.

```
=LET(h,COLUMN(A:L)-1,m,ROW(1:60)-1,a,ABS(30*h-11*m/2),TEXTJOIN("
",1,IF((a=A1)+(a=360-A1),h&","&m,"")))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com), <s>66</s> 61 bytes

```
i=[262,458]
f(n)=(mod(floor(in/60),-12)+12,mod(i,60)n).unique
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jkxmkzjgtn)

*-5 bytes thanks to Aiden Chow*

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 71 bytes

```csharp
(int a)=>new[]{458*a,262*a}.Select(x=>((x/60+11)%12+1,x%60)).Distinct()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVDLTsMwELznK1YVlezWmDhtQ9s0uZSHiuDUAwfEwRgXLKWOiN0SFOXbwxoQQkje8c6sZXtGuVPlVH9wxr7A9sN5vc@iv4zfGvv2T1pXZamVN5V1/FpbXRuVRaqUzsE6aiNwXnqj4FiZZ7iTxhIaAcpwdbBqZaxnm0t72OtaPpV6RYKARYsCdnkfKEiaF1a/Pzy209l8JFmSJiPZ8a0Oz5ImLwhpztJ4LAQdimQsWDNMY0r5hXHeWDxC@2xX1VqqVyBHWYMFY@H7xpjBAkvMEaYzBhPc0yAkAVAQkwA4TBicL7BN5whfnZh1aAXWaLwqNb@vjdeYjybO15gPv6nQ7IABrh2x9PfDkBdwMmgbvsH4xDKOu@UPSQIZUEqzqOv6Tw)

Based on various other answers. Like Jitse's Python 3 solution, I'm using both magic numbers 262 and 458 to get the answers in minutes, modulo 720 minutes. For the hours, I'm using the trick to add 11, take the remainder of dividing by 12, and then add 1 to get a value from 1 to 12. Since duplicate answers for 0 and 180 aren't allowed, I'm using the Distinct function from Linq.

Community guidelines for C# require a type for lambdas hence the `(int a)=>`, if untyped lambdas are OK we can make that `a=>` for a saving of 6 bytes.